# SQL Server : inner join: ambiguous name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have two tables in SQL Server:

[Production].[dbo].[OrderDetails]:

```
CaseId    Gender
-----------------
698       Female
694       Male
676       Male
659       Male
636       Female
624       Female
622       Female
597       Male
579       Male
574       Male
```

[Production].[dbo].[Order]

```
OrderID   SoftAdminOrderID    InfoIDOrderID   Active      
----------------------------------------------------
33425999      698             196665           1
33425984      694             196662           1
33425984      694             196663           0   
33425609      676             196645           1
33425270      659             196625           1
33424973      636             196609           1
33424716      624             196594           1
33424704      622             196592           1
33424500      597             196568           1
33424340      579             196552           1
33424281      574             196548           1
```

and I want to obtain the gender with an inner join:

```
 SELECT TOP (10) 
     [OrderID],
     [SoftAdminOrderID],
     [InfoID],
     [Active],
    /* [Gender]*/
 FROM
     [Production].[dbo].[Order]
 /*INNER JOIN 
     [Production].[dbo].[OrderDetails] ON [Production].[dbo].[Order].SoftAdminOrderID = [Production].[dbo].[OrderDetails].CaseId*/
 where Active = 1
 order by SoftAdminOrderID desc
```

But I get an error when I remove the comment from the inner join:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
>   Ambiguous column name 'CaseId'.

I do not understand why it is considered ambiguous.

Comment: The error does not match the query.

Comment: The tables, as you have shown them, have no column names in common, nor does your query reveal this as being a problem.  Are you _certain_ that you posted the correct table structure and query?

Comment: ^^ What they said. The code snippet you posted is not where the error is being thrown.

Comment: Sorry, I slightly modified my real case and forgot something. Now I corrected, adding ,[gender]. This example should reflect my real case.

Comment: Are you sure this is the entire query ? The errormessage should not appear with this query so there must be something left out

Comment: does not seem to produce an error related with caseid field

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake: I omitted a crucial column: "Active". Indeed, without "where Active = 1" there are multiple columns with the same SoftAdminOrderID in the second table, and this is probably generating the error.

Comment: What else is missing from the table definitions you have provided or the query? There are no ambiguous column names in the information you have provided to date.

Comment: I entered line 3 in the second table. That line disappears when I enter "where Active = 1" condition, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If that's really happening then why don't you solve it by adding table alias to the columns as below:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    o.[OrderID]
    ,o.[SoftAdminOrderID]
    ,o.[InfoID]
    ,od.[Gender]
 FROM [Production].[dbo].[Order] AS o
 INNER JOIN [Production].[dbo].[OrderDetails] AS od ON o.SoftAdminOrderID = od.CaseId
```

Comment: this does not matter. With or without using an alias the errormessage he posted cannot occur with the posted query and table design

Comment: Yeah, I guess too there is some lacking in the information what `OP` has given here but ultimately the solution is only this. People still voting up even the error source is unknown.

Comment: why this question got an upvote i also do not understand, that is correct